# Question mark in reserved keyword

Tags: lex, ply

I am trying to write a parser for LOLCODE <s>GOD, WHAT I AM DOING???</s>
 (just in case to explain those strange words=) )

So, I need to have tokens for `O RLY?` and `YA RLY`.
I am trying to do like this:

```
reserved = { ...,
  'O':    'IF_O',
  'RLY?': 'IF_RLY',
  'YA':   'THEN_YA',
  'RLY':  'THEN_RLY',  ...}
tokens = reserved.values() + (...)

t_IF_O          = r'O'
t_IF_RLY        = r'RLY\?'
t_THEN_YA       = r'YA'
t_THEN_RLY      = r'RLY'
```

And when I write `O RLY?` it is parsed like `IF_O THEN_RLY` and an undefined symbol `?`.

If I replace RLY? with, for example, RLYY, replacing in dictionary `RLY?: 'IF_RLY'` -> `'RLYY': 'IF_RLY'` and `t_IF_RLY = r'RLYY'`, then it works for `O RLYY`.

So I think this is a problem with question marks in reserved words and do not know a workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I can't reproduce this problem. Here is a working sample (ply=3.10, python=3.6):

```
import ply.lex as lex

tokens = (
    'IF_O',
    'IF_RLY',
    'THEN_YA',
    'THEN_RLY'
)

t_IF_O = r'O'
t_IF_RLY = r'RLY\?'
t_THEN_YA = r'YA'
t_THEN_RLY = r'RLY'

t_ignore = ' \t'


def t_error(t):
    print(t)

lexer = lex.lex()
lexer.input('O RLY?')
while True:
    token = lexer.token()
    if token is None:
        break
    print(token)
```

And it prints:

```
LexToken(IF_O,'O',1,0)
LexToken(IF_RLY,'RLY?',1,2)
```